# how to acces values from array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is my addToCart method in which I am adding the courses to `user_cart` column in users table.

```
                public function addToCart($id){

              $course = Course::findOrfail($id); 

              $user =Auth::user();

              $cart_array = array();

              $cart = $user->user_cart;
              if ($cart == '') {
                array_push($cart_array, array('id' => $course->id));
                // print_r($cart_array);
                  } else {
                      $founder = false;
                      $cart_array = json_decode($cart, true);
                      for ($i = 0; $i < count($cart_array); $i++) {
                          $cart_for_eacch_course = $cart_array[$i];
                          if ($cart_for_eacch_course['id'] == $course->id) {
                              $founder = true;
                          }
                      }
                    if (!$founder) {
                  array_push($cart_array, array('id' => $course->id));
                }
                  }


              $data['id'] = json_encode($cart_array);

              $update = User::where('id',$user->id)->update(['user_cart'=> $cart_array]);

              return redirect()->back();
              }
```

And this is my showcart method in which I am taking the courses from users table `user_cart` column array.

```
          public function showcart(){

           $user = Auth::user();


        $array = $user->user_cart;
        print_r($array);


            return view('frontend.my_cart', compact('academic','nonacademic','instructor','coc','my_cart'));

   
           }
```

And when I am displaying it I am getting the output as follows:

```
[{"id":84},{"id":86}]
```

Now can you tell me that how to loop them so I can get the courses? I tried by using a `foreach` loop for `$array` but it shows me the error of invalid argument supplied for `foreach()`

Comment: And what exactly is `$user->user_cart` returning?

Comment: Yes, we need to see how user_cart is being built. Also, please format your code properly, it helps everyone involved. Even people who may have issues similar to yours in the future.

Comment: [{"id":84},{"id":86}]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are building the array into a JSON or string field within your database on the **User** object.  The resulting array appears to be stored as a JSON string, so decode and then loop:

```
$array = json_decode( $user->user_cart, true );
foreach($array as $key => $val){
     dump $key;
     dump $val;
}
```